# Is it possible to tether scrollbars together?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open up 2 images within a modal separated by a black line, and there
is a scroll bar for each separate window and overflow is set to scroll. The images in each
window are identical except they've been enlarged by different algorithms from their original
form (don't worry about any of this, it's just to give you an idea of the purpose). I want it so that when you are comparing images that overflow, the scroll bars are tethered or bound to each other so that when you scroll on one window, it scrolls on the other window.

If you need a specific code example I'll present one later, because I just want to get an idea
of how this might be possible for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to listen for scroll events and then perform the same scroll on the second container. You may have to use some logic if the images are different sizes however.

[This](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) should help you get started.

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/r4EjQ/)

**EDIT**

For archival purposes I have provided the jQuery used in the example.

```
$( '#one' ).scroll( function() {
    $( '#two' ).scrollTop( $( '#one' ).scrollTop() );
} );
```

Comment: I've heard of the scroll event, but could you give an example of how I might trigger the same scroll event on another container?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to an example.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to hook the `onscroll` event of both scrolling elements and in each one set the `scrollTop` of the other to what you scrolled to. Also, make sure you set and clear a boolean before and after so you don't get mutual recursion.

Comment: +1 for catch on on possible infinite event recursion!

Comment: Thanks! I did have to implement this once (mutual scrolling diff) and the recursion bit was a small but important detail. :)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine would have to usa an `object.onscroll` event for each picture.  Just assign the scoll value to the other picture of the current picture following

```
object.addEventListener ("scroll", handler, useSomething);
object.attachEvent ("onscroll", handler);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an iframe - put both pictures in the file to be shown in the iframe, then you only need one scroll bar.